# Two sisters run into the woods. Eldest sister is captured by a witch and turned into a witch

Tags: story-identification

Okay, so when I was maybe 7 or 8 (so in 2005 or 2006) there was this show/movie I came across on Scifi.

I don't remember a WHOLE lot about it clearly, but I remember there were two little girls, sisters, and they were running around together gleefully through the woods. They ran into a witch, and the witch couldn't harm them if they were together, but the younger sister got scared and ran away and the older sister got snatched by the witch when she did. Thus the older sister became an evil witch herself and the entire rest of what I saw was the adventure that ensued, the younger sister I think not even remembering that it's her fault her sister is evil.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: I also remembered this part but never the title. I remembered the sister who ran away ran to her mother and was crying. but then the older sister came back and her mother was like "See? She's fine" and the older sister glared at the younger one. Then I remember later on they were fighting against the evil magic and the younger one said to the older one "No! I'm not leaving you again!"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

"Tin Man" (2007 TV mini series)

This was a Sci-Fi Channel original movie that aired in three parts and was based on The Wizard of Oz. Here is part of the plot summary from Wikipedia which I think matches your description:

> As children DG and Azkadellia were very close, but that changed when
>   DG accidentally released the spirit of an ancient, evil witch (Karin
>   Konoval) from a cave. The sisters' magic would have protected them if
>   they stayed together linking hands, but DG fled and the witch
>   possessed Azkadellia. DG realizes that all of the tragedies which have
>   befallen the O.Z. are the result of that mistake she made as a child.

It looks like the entire mini-series can be viewed on YouTube currently, in 3 different parts, but here is a trailer from YouTube: